# Set time value to tomorrow 9 am

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I set certain `DateTime` value to tomorrow `9:00 AM`

For example:

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).//setTime to 9:00 AM
```

Is there some SetDateTime value functionality that I don't know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use two methods

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(9)
```

Comment: `+1` for the fastest best answer here. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: perfect - nice and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this `DateTime` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
DateTime tomorrow = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,
                                 DateTime.Now.Month,
                                 DateTime.Now.Day + 1,
                                 9,
                                 0,
                                 0);
Console.WriteLine(tomorrow);
```

Output will be;

```
18.03.2014 09:00:00
```

As CompuChip [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449071/set-time-value-to-tomorrow-9-am#comment34143294_22449104), this throws exception if the current day is the last day of the month.

Better you can use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property with [`AddDays(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`AddHours(9)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because it get's to midnight of the current day. Like;

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(9);
```

Comment: Just curious, does this also work if the day goes out of range? E.g. does this work on the last day of the month?

Comment: @CompuChip According to the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it won't work and will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Using `DateTime.Today` will definitely work though.

Comment: @CompuChip You are definitely right. It won't work for the last day of the montrh. That's why I added to use `DateTime.Today` property for better approach. Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;
DateTime Tomorrow = new DateTime(dt.Year,dt.Month,dt.Day+1,9,0,0);
```